# why my mongodb balancer doesn't run against all shards server?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.4

I have set up a three mongo shards cluster and one `mongos` instance. I want to check how the balancer work among this cluster. I have enabled sharding on one collection. Below is the output of `sh.status`.

```
mongos> sh.status()
--- Sharding Status --- 
  sharding version: {
    "_id" : 1,
    "minCompatibleVersion" : 5,
    "currentVersion" : 6,
    "clusterId" : ObjectId("592374a0639dd3cda3dbb0b5")
}
  shards:
    {  "_id" : "shard01",  "host" : "shard01/hoth.local:27018,hoth.local:27019,hoth.local:27020",  "state" : 1 }
    {  "_id" : "shard02",  "host" : "shard02/hoth.local:27021,hoth.local:27022,hoth.local:27023",  "state" : 1 }
    {  "_id" : "shard03",  "host" : "shard03/hoth.local:27024,hoth.local:27025,hoth.local:27026",  "state" : 1 }
  active mongoses:
    "3.4.4" : 1
 autosplit:
    Currently enabled: yes
  balancer:
    Currently enabled:  yes
    Currently running:  no
        Balancer lock taken at Tue May 23 2017 09:30:41 GMT+1000 (AEST) by ConfigServer:Balancer
    Failed balancer rounds in last 5 attempts:  0
    Migration Results for the last 24 hours: 
        7898 : Failed with error 'aborted', from shard01 to shard02
  databases:
    {  "_id" : "shards",  "primary" : "shard01",  "partitioned" : true }
        shards.users
            shard key: { "user.age" : 1 }
            unique: false
            balancing: true
            chunks:
                shard01 80
            too many chunks to print, use verbose if you want to force print
```

From above output, I can see that all data in the collection `shards.users` are saved in `shard01`. I don't understand how to ensure the balancer among this cluster. Is there anything wrong with my settings?

From the above error `7898 : Failed with error 'aborted', from shard01 to shard02`, it says something wrong with the migration. I didn't find any information on log file about this error. I have tried to enable/disable balancerState at the meantime monitor the log file and it only gave me below information:

```
2017-05-25T09:58:43.806+1000 I NETWORK  [thread2] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:53973 #78 (1 connection now open)
2017-05-25T09:58:43.807+1000 I NETWORK  [conn78] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:53973 conn78: { application: { name: "MongoDB Shell" }, driver: { name: "MongoDB Internal Client", version: "3.4.4" }, os: { type: "Darwin", name: "Mac OS X", architecture: "x86_64", version: "16.5.0" } }
2017-05-25T09:59:08.192+1000 I -        [conn78] end connection 127.0.0.1:53973 (1 connection now open)
2017-05-25T09:59:50.388+1000 I NETWORK  [thread2] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:53980 #79 (1 connection now open)
```

Below is the output from `getShardMap`.

```
mongos> db.runCommand({getShardMap:1})
{
    "map" : {
        "config" : "configRepl/hoth.local:27027",
        "configRepl/hoth.local:27027" : "configRepl/hoth.local:27027",
        "hoth.local:27018" : "shard01/hoth.local:27018,hoth.local:27019,hoth.local:27020",
        "hoth.local:27019" : "shard01/hoth.local:27018,hoth.local:27019,hoth.local:27020",
        "hoth.local:27020" : "shard01/hoth.local:27018,hoth.local:27019,hoth.local:27020",
        "hoth.local:27021" : "shard02/hoth.local:27021,hoth.local:27022,hoth.local:27023",
        "hoth.local:27022" : "shard02/hoth.local:27021,hoth.local:27022,hoth.local:27023",
        "hoth.local:27023" : "shard02/hoth.local:27021,hoth.local:27022,hoth.local:27023",
        "hoth.local:27024" : "shard03/hoth.local:27024,hoth.local:27025,hoth.local:27026",
        "hoth.local:27025" : "shard03/hoth.local:27024,hoth.local:27025,hoth.local:27026",
        "hoth.local:27026" : "shard03/hoth.local:27024,hoth.local:27025,hoth.local:27026",
        "hoth.local:27027" : "configRepl/hoth.local:27027",
        "shard01" : "shard01/hoth.local:27018,hoth.local:27019,hoth.local:27020",
        "shard01/hoth.local:27018,hoth.local:27019,hoth.local:27020" : "shard01/hoth.local:27018,hoth.local:27019,hoth.local:27020",
        "shard02" : "shard02/hoth.local:27021,hoth.local:27022,hoth.local:27023",
        "shard02/hoth.local:27021,hoth.local:27022,hoth.local:27023" : "shard02/hoth.local:27021,hoth.local:27022,hoth.local:27023",
        "shard03" : "shard03/hoth.local:27024,hoth.local:27025,hoth.local:27026",
        "shard03/hoth.local:27024,hoth.local:27025,hoth.local:27026" : "shard03/hoth.local:27024,hoth.local:27025,hoth.local:27026"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: What is the output `sh.isBalancerRunning()` of this command?

Comment: it returns false

Comment: As it says, "7898 : Failed with error 'aborted', from shard01 to shard02". You must check log files from primaries. Nodes and config servers. Answer is almost always in log files

Comment: Does it balance between 01-->03?

Comment: @SqlWorldWide It doesn't balance between 01 -> 03 as well.

Comment: @JJussi I have updated the log information. I didn't find any error on the log file related to the error from `sh.status` command

Comment: I suggest you check your config servers and make sure all nodes in the cluster are aware of config server.

Comment: I added the getShardMap output on the post. Does this approve the aware of config server?

Comment: Please do manual moveChunk and report result/error. sh.moveChunk("shards.users", { user.age: {minKey:1} }, "shard03")

Comment: Do you have a cursor open to the collection with the `noTimeout` option set? Try to increase your logging verbosity until you can see the error -- usually level 2 is enough for most purposes (see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#systemLog.component.sharding.verbosity)